# Writing J/XFS code to interact with ATM peripherals

Tags: java, c++, xfs, cen-xfs

I have been trying to learn J/XFS and am stuck at a point where I am unable to start. Though the specifications go in detail about the available calls and the API, there are very little or no sample code snippets which shows how code can be written to interact with ATM peripherals.

1. Where can I get sample code snippets for CEN/XFS or J/XFS?
2. Are there virtual peripherals out there on which I can try out the code?

Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: I don't recommend you to start with J/XFS. Because, not all of the vendors support it. If they do, they could be not supporting for all devices.

Comment: I haven't seen any open source examples about cen/XFS yet. So, you should read the documentations and try on provided APIs on https://www.cen.eu/work/areas/ICT/eBusiness/Pages/WS-XFS.aspx
Yes, that's a pain to understand all of the standarts and develop it from the start point. Good luck.